# Помощь с рекурсией

Tags: c++, рекурсия

Как запустить данную рекурсию? нужно найти [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{   
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
    float x=0; int n=0;
    cout<<"Введите число для вычисления степени: "<<endl;
    cin>>x;
    cout<<"Введите степень числа: "<<endl;
    cin>>n;
    cout<<"Число "<<x<<" в степени "<<n<<" Равно "<<stepen()<<endl;
    return 0;
}

double stepen (float x=0, int n=0)
{
    if (n=0) return 1;
    else if (n<0) return stepen(1/pow(x,abs(n)));
    else return stepen(x*pow(x,n-1));
}
```

Comment: Что значит "запустить"? С чем именно у вас проблемы? И что именно вам нужно сделать?

Comment: у меня не запускается программа. Т.е, не могу связать главную программу с функцией. Не доходит ум. Эту тему я вообще не понял, сам учу кое-как

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ощущение, что вы, как бы выразиться... не очень понимаете не только рекурсию, но и сам язык.

```
double stepen (double x, int n)
{
    if (n == 0) return 1;
    else if (n<0) return 1.0/stepen(x,-n);
    else return x*stepen(x,n-1);
}


int main ()
{   
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
    double x;
    int n;
    cout<<"Введите число для вычисления степени: "<<endl;
    cin>>x;
    cout<<"Введите степень числа: "<<endl;
    cin>>n;
    cout<<"Число "<<x<<" в степени "<<n<<" Равно "<< stepen(x,n) <<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: спасибо. Язык, вроде как, понимаю. Если Вы про Double и float, я забыл заменить, разные способы пробовал))
upd. Ааа, не все. Короче, я понял, надо срочно подтягивать язык. Иду дальше грызть гранит программирования) Спасибо Вам.

Comment: Как минимум - использование функции до объявления, присвоение вместо сравнения... Непонятные значения аргументов по умолчанию.